# PHP: get the working ethernet device

Tags: php, linux, ethernet

I have 2 Ethernet devices(eth0 and eth1). The cable is connected just to eth1. I need to execute few iptables commands through PHP but I also need to enter there the working ethernet device. May be I'm too stupid but I couldn`t write the source code and better not to see such a mess. My OS is CentOS 6.9 (Final). I tryed to "cat /proc/net/dev" and to separate them, tryed to "ifconfig" and separate the data, but still no luck. Any idea how in PHP to get the ethernet devices(not wifi) that receives and transmit data?

Comment: /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate

Comment: nope, it`s not working. It`s a script in which you are supposed not to know your ethernet devices and the script to find your devices and to show them (without lo0, sit0 and venet0). May be you have en0 but you don`t know it, so the script scans the output from "ifconfig" let`s say and outputs for you only the ethernet device which is receiving and sending packets.

Comment: Need something like "lshw -class network | grep "logical name" | head -10 | awk '{print $3}'" but this one prints also the not connected ethernet device

Comment: `lshw` gets its information from the same location.

Comment: Ok, but you still didn`t get it. /sys/class/net/??/operstate -> I need the script to understand by itself what is ??. How this can happen?

Comment: Let me explain it more clear (I think). The script is adding an OpenVZ container to the system. It`s supposed to add also 2 iptables rules which needs the "eth*" device. As the script is going to be public and not everybody knows his/her ethernet devices, the script is supposed to discover them automatic. So any idea how the script can discover which ethernet devices a server has and which one is active?